# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, …) 0 non-na cases

Tags: r

I'm using this command before the regression because I need just the positive incomes:

```
pnad <-subset(dados, renda_mref_trab_pri_sref > 0)
```

my command is:

```
mqo_mincer_homem <-lm(formula = log(renda_trab_pri_10/(horas_trab_pri_sref*4)) ~ anos_educ  + exper  +  exper_sq  + d_bca + d_agro + d_indu + d_serv + d_apub + d_formal + d_rural + d_no + d_se + d_su + d_co , data=subset(dados, d_fem==0))
```

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, …) 
>   0 non-na cases

I tried all the `na.option` and also set the `sum(is.na("variable"))` for each term used in the regression and there is no NA anymore:

```
sum(is.na("idade"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("dados$renda_trab_pri_10"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("dados$horas_trab_pri_sref"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("idade"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("dados$renda_trab_pri_10"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("dados$horas_trab_pri_sref"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("anos_educ"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("ativ_emp_trab_pri_sref_10"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("pos_ocup_sref"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("exper_sq"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_bca"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_agro"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_indu"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_serv"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_apub"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_no"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_se"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_su"))
[1] 0
sum(is.na("d_co"))
[1] 0
```

anyway the command still returns the same error message

what possibly am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I need this lm just for men... I want R to select just the men data. `d_fem==1` is for women.
I tried "dados" and "pnad" but the error is the same

Comment: @ZheyuanLi 
> `sum(complete.cases(subset(dados, d_fem==0)))
[1] 0`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi how may i fix this to aplly `lm`, please?

Comment: Is it expected that you have no complete cases? If yes, multiple imputation would be an option.

Comment: I think so. The data I use is much like CPS (Current Population Survey) but for Brazil. I might search more about multiple imputation because I have no idea how to use it. It's my first time using R alone. 
Thank you so much for your help!